# How to report LIVE electrical wiring dangling in public swimming area for children?a

Tags: electrical, wiring

5 live electrical lines and inadequate junction box dangle in the childtens' swim area every medium and high tide at Boston Harbor Marina. They refuse to change it. It us an eminent ESD waiting to happen, as there are families and babies swimming within inches of the hot wires and junction box every warm day.. I have several pictures but they are too big for your system to upload. PLEASE make the marina safe for their customers' children. They get away with so many neighborhood disruptions and public dangers......we wonder "why". Sincerely, Patty Burfoot representing Boston Harbor concerned citizens

Comment: Contact a safety authority.

Comment: This is not an appropriate post for here...but I hope you can find resolution before someone gets hurt.

Comment: This concern does not belong on this forum.  Create a blogspot account, write a blog entry (with your pictures) and then buzz it up on Facebook, Twitter, NextDoor etc.   That will get you a response quickly.  By the way, how do you know they're not **telecomm cables**?  (Prepare for that response).

Comment: While your question is off topic a safety concern deserves a response. If is within the Boston City limits contact code enforcement (617) 635-4896

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal issue that requires dealing with local authorities.

Answer (score 1):

I would call the Harbor Authority, if there is such a entity.
I'd call the Harbor police, if there is such an entity as well.

Good luck

Comment: If that fails, try a local paper.

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out who, call or write to their Insurance carrier. Money talks surprisingly loudly.

A city council or other elected body could get your ball rolling.  Have you tried hizz- or her- honor?  A call to non-emergency police number might do it - liability costs lots of money, nobody wants to be responsible if they’re going to be shown to have ignored the situation reports.

Not sure this is the most appropriate forum for your question. And that’s one more try, find a concerned forum online.

Answer (score 0):

Call the power company, harbor police, general manager or Harbor Master, etc.

Try calling the local TV news. They love chasing down that kind of stuff.